# Websphere 8.x and REST

Tags: websphere, jax-rs

I am working to get REST services working in Websphere 8.x but when I use the following web.xml...

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
  xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd"
  version="3.0"> 

<servlet>
    <display-name>jersey</display-name>
    <servlet-name>jersey</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>
                 com.ibm.websphere.jaxrs.server.IBMRestServlet
    </servlet-class>
    <init-param>
         <param-name>com.sun.jersey.config.property.packages</param-name>
         <param-value>org.gleason.rest</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>



<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>jersey</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/rest/*</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>

</web-app>
```

When I try to start the app I get a 404, also eclipse shows the following build error...

> Description    Resource    Path    Location    Type
>   The servlet mapping "jersey" refers to a servlet that is not defined    web.xml /RestTest/WebContent/WEB-INF    Unknown Web Problem

This leads me to believe it is not building properly and that is why my index.html works but the JAX-RS fails.

Can anyone see what I am missing? All the examples revolve around Application, I would rather use package.

Answer (score 2):

WAS has JAX-RS implementation based on Apache Wink. Your configuration shows a mix of Apache Wink and Jersey (another JAX-RS implementation).

Answer (score 1):

You can also configure your rest service only with Annotations in your RestService class, avoiding web.xml configuration

Here is an quick example for testing it with a GET or POST request

```
    import javax.ws.rs.ApplicationPath;
    import javax.ws.rs.Consumes;
    import javax.ws.rs.GET;
    import javax.ws.rs.POST;
    import javax.ws.rs.Path;
    import javax.ws.rs.Produces;
    import javax.ws.rs.core.Application;
    import javax.ws.rs.core.MediaType;

    @ApplicationPath("rest")
    @Path("/service")
    public class RestService extends Application {

        @GET
        @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
        public Map hello() {
            Map map = new HashMap(1);
            map.put("Hello", "I'm a REST Service");
            return map;
        }

        @POST  //
        @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
        @Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
        public Map helloName(HashMap entryMap) {
            Map map = new HashMap(1);
            map.put("Hello", entryMap.get("Name"));
            return map;
        }
    }
```

Comment: This is probably true now that WAS supports these JAX-RS annotations however, this is an old question and that was not always the case.

Comment: See answer above they def changed the version

Answer (score 0):

Here is s simple example how to develop and deploy a REST service in WAS8.
The example is based on an API to manage JSON configs, i.e. listing, fetching, uploading etc.

```
package se.xyz;

import java.util.HashSet;
import java.util.Set;

import javax.ws.rs.ApplicationPath;
import javax.ws.rs.core.Application;

//Use the ApplicationPath annotation do specify the URI path to your REST API
@ApplicationPath("api")
public class RestAPIRegistrationServlet extends Application {

    @Override
    public Set<Object> getSingletons() {
        Set<Object> tSet = new HashSet<Object>();
        //add an instance of your API class to the set of API´s.
        tSet.add(new ConfigRestAPI());
        return tSet;
    }

}
```

Here is the API to manage JSON configs. **Note** that the API is using a ConfigManager to handle the configs. This class is not included in the example.

```
package se.xyz;

import java.util.HashSet;
import java.util.Set;
import java.util.logging.Level;
import java.util.logging.Logger;

import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.ws.rs.Consumes;
import javax.ws.rs.DELETE;
import javax.ws.rs.GET;
import javax.ws.rs.POST;
import javax.ws.rs.PUT;
import javax.ws.rs.Path;
import javax.ws.rs.Produces;
import javax.ws.rs.QueryParam;
import javax.ws.rs.WebApplicationException;
import javax.ws.rs.core.Application;
import javax.ws.rs.core.Context;
import javax.ws.rs.core.MediaType;
import javax.ws.rs.core.Response;
import javax.ws.rs.core.Response.ResponseBuilder;

import org.apache.wink.common.model.wadl.WADLGenerator;

//Specify the ConfigRestAPI part of the URI path
@Path("/configs")
public class ConfigRestAPI{

    private static Logger _LOGGER = Logger.getLogger(ConfigRestAPI.class.getName());

    @javax.ws.rs.OPTIONS
    @Produces("application/vnd.sun.wadl+xml")
    public org.apache.wink.common.model.wadl.Application getOptions(@Context Application app,
            @Context HttpServletRequest aHttpServletRequest) {
        logAccess(aHttpServletRequest);
        Set<Object> tObjectSet = app.getSingletons();
        Set<Class<?>> tClassSet = new HashSet<Class<?>>();
        for (Object tObject : tObjectSet) {
            tClassSet.add(tObject.getClass());
        }
        org.apache.wink.common.model.wadl.Application wadlAppDoc = new WADLGenerator().generate("", tClassSet);
        /* modify the wadlAppDoc JAXB model if you want to add additional information */
        return wadlAppDoc;
    }

    @GET
    @Path("/list")
    @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    public Response list(@Context HttpServletRequest aHttpServletRequest) {

        logAccess(aHttpServletRequest);
        try {

            ResponseBuilder tResponseBuilder =
                    Response.ok(ConfigManager.getInstance().fetchConfigs(), MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON);

            Response tResponse = tResponseBuilder.build();

            return tResponse;

        } catch (Throwable e) {
            _LOGGER.log(Level.SEVERE, e.getMessage(), e);
            throw new WebApplicationException(e, Response.serverError()
                    .entity(e.getClass().getName() + ", Message: " + e.getMessage()).build());
        }

    }

    private boolean isNullOrBlank(String aVal){
        return aVal == null || "".equals(aVal.trim());
    }
    @GET
    @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    public Response fetch(@QueryParam("id") String id, @Context HttpServletRequest aHttpServletRequest) {

        logAccess(aHttpServletRequest);
        try {
            if (isNullOrBlank(id)) {
                return Response.serverError().entity("id cannot be null or blank").build();
            }

            ResponseBuilder tResponseBuilder =
                    Response.ok(ConfigManager.getInstance().fetchConfig(id), MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON);

            Response tResponse = tResponseBuilder.build();

            return tResponse;

        } catch (Throwable e) {
            _LOGGER.log(Level.SEVERE, e.getMessage(), e);
            throw new WebApplicationException(e, Response.serverError()
                    .entity(e.getClass().getName() + ", Message: " + e.getMessage()).build());
        }
    }

    @POST
    @Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    @Produces(MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN)
    public Response store(String aConfig, @QueryParam("id") String id, @Context HttpServletRequest aHttpServletRequest) {

        logAccess(aHttpServletRequest);
        try {
            if (isNullOrBlank(id))  {
                return Response.serverError().entity("id cannot be null or blank").build();
            }
            ConfigManager.getInstance().storeConfig(aConfig, id);
        } catch (Throwable e) {
            _LOGGER.log(Level.SEVERE, e.getMessage(), e);
            throw new WebApplicationException(e, Response.serverError()
                    .entity(e.getClass().getName() + ", Message: " + e.getMessage()).build());
        }
        ResponseBuilder tResponseBuilder = Response.ok();

        Response tResponse = tResponseBuilder.build();

        return tResponse;
    }

    @PUT
    @Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    @Produces(MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN)
    public Response update(String aConfig, @QueryParam("id") String id, @Context HttpServletRequest aHttpServletRequest) {

        logAccess(aHttpServletRequest);

        try {
            if (isNullOrBlank(id))  {
                return Response.serverError().entity("id cannot be null or blank").build();
            }
            ConfigManager.getInstance().updateConfig(aConfig, id);
        } catch (Throwable e) {
            _LOGGER.log(Level.SEVERE, e.getMessage(), e);
            throw new WebApplicationException(e, Response.serverError()
                    .entity(e.getClass().getName() + ", Message: " + e.getMessage()).build());
        }
        ResponseBuilder tResponseBuilder = Response.ok();

        Response tResponse = tResponseBuilder.build();

        return tResponse;
    }

    @DELETE
    @Produces(MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN)
    public Response delete(@QueryParam("id") String id, @Context HttpServletRequest aHttpServletRequest) {

        logAccess(aHttpServletRequest);

        try {
            if (isNullOrBlank(id))  {
                return Response.serverError().entity("id cannot be null or blank").build();
            }
            ConfigManager.getInstance().deleteConfig(id);
        } catch (Throwable e) {
            _LOGGER.log(Level.SEVERE, e.getMessage(), e);
            throw new WebApplicationException(e, Response.serverError()
                    .entity(e.getClass().getName() + ", Message: " + e.getMessage()).build());
        }
        ResponseBuilder tResponseBuilder = Response.ok();
        Response tResponse = tResponseBuilder.build();

        return tResponse;
    }

    private static void logAccess(HttpServletRequest aHttpServletRequest) {

        if (_LOGGER.isLoggable(Level.FINE))
            _LOGGER.fine(aHttpServletRequest.getRequestURI() + " called from: " + aHttpServletRequest.getRemoteHost()
                    + " (" + aHttpServletRequest.getRemoteAddr() + ")");

    }

}
```

After deploying the REST API you can call it using:
Http GET on the URI /ContextPath/api/configs/list for the list operation.

For further reading:
http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/websphere/techjournal/1305_gunderson/1305_gunderson.html

Comment: So does this mean it now autoscans packages and you do not need a web.xml entry?

Answer (score 0):

In your server.xml,
try to remove  `<feature>jaxrs-1.1</feature>` 
like this

```
  <featureManager>
        <feature>jsp-2.2</feature>
        <feature>localConnector-1.0</feature>
<!--         <feature>jaxrs-1.1</feature> -->
    </featureManager>
```

There is conflict with 2 JAX-RS implementation.